# Choose step values in sliderInput() widget

Tags: r, shiny

I am not sure this is possible with the standard `shiny::sliderInput()` in shiny (javascript solution also welcome). I have a range of discrete values that I want to use in the slider widget but this range has "intermittent" steps:

```
> # MWE
> 
> # step sequence is c(2, 4, 4)
> steps <- rep(c(2, 4, 4), 5, each = 1)
> 
> steps[1:3]
[1] 2 4 4
> 
> # this is the sequence
> years <- Reduce(`+`, var.freq, init = 2010, accumulate = T)
> 
> years
 [1] 2010 2012 2016 2020 2022 2026 2030 2032 2036 2040 2042 2046 2050 2052 2056 2060
> 
> # minimum and maximum values for slider
> minmax <- sapply(c(min, max), function(x) x(years))
> 
> minmax
[1] 2010 2060
```

What I want is a slider that will let the user select only the values specified in `years`. I understand that I can transform the object selected in the slider to conform the values in `years` but I am more interested in the aesthetics of the slider and I want to avoid confusion for the user. The `step` argument in `shiny::sliderInput()` seems to take only the first element in the `steps` object:

```
# define UI
ui <- function(){

  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Varying steps..."), # define title of panel

    sidebarLayout( # create layout for shiny app
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput(inputId = "range", 
                    label = h4(HTML("<b>Year interval:</b>")), 
                    min = minmax[[1]], max = minmax[[2]], 
                    value = minmax, 
                    ticks = T, 
                    step = steps,
                    sep = "")
      ), 
      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("result")
      )
    )

  )
}

# server side
server <- function(input, output){

  output$result <- renderPrint({
    input$range
  }) 

}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try function `sliderTextInput` from [`shinyWidgets`](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets), it allow you to use a slider with custom values for choices :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

years <- c(2010 ,2012, 2016, 2020, 2022, 2026,
           2030, 2032, 2036, 2040, 2042, 2046,
           2050, 2052, 2056, 2060)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderTextInput(
    inputId = "range", label = h4(tags$b("Year interval:")), 
    choices = years, selected = range(years), 
    grid = TRUE
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$res <- renderPrint(input$range)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```