# How to use different `step` and breaks in a sliderInput in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have this `sliderInput`:

```
library(shiny)
sliderInput("year",
                 label = "In what year were you born?",
                 min = 1920,
                 max = 2010,
                 value = 1940,
                 step = 1
)
```

I want the rendered breaks on the slider to be in 10s like 1920, 1930, 1940, ..., 2010. With the step value of 1, what parameter can I change to achive that? `ticks` takes `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Consider using `shinyWidgets` (see [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48952385/3460670))

Comment: @Ben `shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput` does not have a `step` parameter. So, whatever `choices` I provide make the `step`. I need `step` to be 1 and the rendered breaks to increment in 10s. The example uses `choices` alone.

Comment: It would be nice if `sliderInput` offered a `choices=` or `breaks=` argument, but I don't think it's currently possibly in basic `shiny`.